# A question over Series expansion of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion, bessel-functions

My question may appear naif or unclear but let me try the same.

> Is there any possibility that a sufficiently regular function defined from a domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded to $\mathbb{R}$, has/gets a series expansion where the radial part is made by Bessel functions and the angular part is made by sines and cosines? In polar coordinates I mean.

Any possible example though?

Comment: to clarify: the series expansion you seek is in powers of which variable? --- in this connection, if I may, I noticed you deleted this recent [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371749/asymptotic-expansion-analysis-of-this-integral/371758#371758) of yours, and thereby also deleted the answer you had received to that question; could you perhaps undelete the question, so that the answer is not lost?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I beg your pardon, I deleted it because I thought I completely wrote a wrong integral (I was reviewing my notes). In any case, I undeleted it and I accepted your answer which is great anyway! :)
For what concerns this question, I thought a series expansion in terms of both $R$ and $\theta$, where maybe the angular part is a sum in $n\theta$ (with sine and/or cosine).

Comment: thanks, a follow-up question: if the radial part is a series expansion in $R$, in what sense could one call a term $R^n$ in such a series a "Bessel function" ?